# Is this limit correct??

Tags: limits, proof-verification

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}h^2\cos \left ( \frac{1}{h} \right )=0$$ since $$-h^2 \leq h^2\cos \left ( \frac{1}{h} \right ) \leq h^2$$ and both the limits of the upper bound and lower bound are zero as $h$ goes to zero?

Comment: Yes. This is an application of the Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: Okay thanks. I have seen similar proofs but they use $-|h|^2$ instead and same on the right?Is that necessary?

Comment: If $x$ is real, then $|x|^2=x^2$. However, the Squeeze Theorem does not require you to take the absolute value of a function.

Comment: okay but what about the statement $$-x \leq x\sin(x) \leq x$$ substitute $x=-\pi$ then you get $$\pi \leq 0 \leq -\pi$$ which is obviously not true here.

Comment: It is not true that $-x\leq x\sin x\leq x$. It is true that $-h^2\leq h^2\cos(1/h)\leq h^2$. So "what about" one inequality being true and another false? Not all inequalities are true?

Comment: Matt-- from $-1 \le \sin x \le 1$ you can't "multiply through by $x$" since $x$ doesn't have constant sign. But multiplying by $|x|$ would be OK and preserve the inequality.

Comment: Okay thanks coffeemath. I think that explains it well. So I can always multiply through by an absolute value because we can preserve the equality signs? Wouldn't it make sense to always multiply through by abs values just in case.

Comment: If you multiple by a positive value then you preserve the signs. If you multiple by a negative they flip. Multiplying by a variable as you demonstrated is problematic unless it is definitely positive or definitely negative.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct. For the inequality, since $-1\leqslant\cos x\leqslant 1$ for all $x$, it follows that $$-1\leqslant\cos\left(\dfrac{1}{h}\right)\leqslant 1\implies- h^2\leqslant h^2\cos\left(\dfrac{1}{h}\right)\leqslant h^2,$$ since $h^2$ is positive. Hence by the Squeeze Theorem we get our desired result.